# Understanding what a particular proc code does

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, proc

I wanted to get an idea as to what what the these two proc blocks do. I am reviewing some code and I came across this.

```
PARSE_TIME = Proc.new do |field|
Time.at(field.to_i / 1000)
end

RENDER_TIME = Proc.new do |field|
field.to_i * 1000
end
```

Thanks!

Comment: It is hard to tell without usage examples. My guess is that you are storing timestamps in the database, however you just want approximate time and you decided to store it without 3 last digits (to save space?). It also might be used for communication with another webservice which is using different timestamp format. All depend on the actual usage of those constant.

Comment: That being said: it is wrong anyway to keep procs as constants.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might call these constants like next:

```
PARSE_TIME.call 1400000000000
# => "2014-05-13 18:53:20 +0200"
RENDER_TIME.call 100
# => 100000
```

The methods are a bit weird, as Time.at accepts a parameter that represents the seconds from January 1st, 1970 ([Unix or Epoch time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time)) and dividing this number by 1000 doesn't represent something familiar.

The other one only multiplies you parameter by 1000, quite a silly operation that usually doesn't deserve a function by itself.

Regards

Comment: According to the docs, it actually looks like `Time.at` wants input in the form of seconds since the epoch, not miliseconds.